# Equivalent of teamcity.build.branch.is_default in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity

Is there an equivalent of %teamcity.build.branch.is_default% in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't.  You can see what is available as [predefined build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts).

You can get to it though with a combination of Build.SourceBranch and using the [Get Repository API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get%20repository?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), which has a property for default branch.